# How can I get both the email and name of an account that signed up using clerk's OAuth authentication?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, clerk

I've been working to implement OAuth authentication to my login page, more specifically, for google and microsoft. In order to make the process easier, I'm trying to make use of clerk to implement both of these. However, I'm having trouble in retrieving both the name and the email of the account used for the sign-up. I've been doing this implementation using React.js.

For starters here is one of the component in question:

```
import { AuthenticateWithRedirectCallback, useSignUp, useSession } from "@clerk/clerk-react";
import useAuth from '../hooks/auth/useLogin';
import { OAuthStrategy } from "@clerk/types";
   
export function SignUpOAuthButtonGoogle() {
  const { signUp } = useSignUp();
  const { session } = useSession();
  const { SignInOAuth } = useAuth();

    const registerAccountOAuth = async (strategy: OAuthStrategy) => {
      
      return signUp?.authenticateWithRedirect({
        strategy,
        redirectUrl: "/",
        redirectUrlComplete: "/",
        continueSignUp: true
      }).finally(() => {
        const user = session?.user
        const name = user?.firstName ? user?.firstName : ""  + user?.lastName ? user?.lastName : ""

        if(user && name && user.primaryEmailAddress)
          SignInOAuth(name , user.primaryEmailAddress.toString())
      });      
    }
   
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => registerAccountOAuth("oauth_google")}>
            Sign up with Google
        </button>
      </div>
    );
}
```

The problem presents itself in the constants of `user` and `name`, as in they are always null, despite specifying that I want the information after finishing the sign-up with the `finally` method in the promise. I need this information in order to at the very least register the account's email and name in my database in the `SignInOAuth` method.

What I did:
I tried signing up with the component I specified into one of my google accounts. I was expecting a call to an endpoint in an api url with "/register" (made by the method `SignInOAuth`) when watching the requests made but no such call is happens.